# Bogus "Undeclared Identifier" errors from the compiler?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-2007

I am writing a designtime package in Delphi 2007.

I decided to move some event type declarations into their own `Events`unit so they can be used in multiple units. When I did the compiler started complaining `Undeclared identifier: 'Event Name'` in the units where these events were originally declared. The type declarations are all in the `interface` section of the `Events` unit and I have added the `Events` unit to the other units' uses clause but its like the compiler is completely ignoring the `Events` unit.

The IDE has no trouble finding the declarations when you <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Click in the type name from another unit. Hovering the mouse over the type name displays the unit its declared in along with its parameters. Even the usually craptastic and paranoid *Error Insight* feature of the IDE doesn't see a problem. Only the compiler complains about it.

I tried reproducing this problem in another, simpler package project to try to isolate it but I can't reproduce it.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before and is there a work around?

Comment: Did you actually included the new unit in your project?

Comment: Yes. It is in the dpk and shows in the project manager. I've even checked the dproj file and there is a DCCReference for it. And it's in the same folder as all the other unit files using it.

Comment: How can we reproduce this so that we know we are running the same code as you?

Comment: This sounds like an issue where the compiler is finding a different copy of the dcu than what would be produced by the source open in the IDE. Check for old dcus for the complaining unit on your drive, and delete all that you find (including any in your project folder), and then do a `Project->Build`. Check again for the .dcu on your drive, and see if there are any you don't expect to be there (or one  in a different location than where you'd expect it to be).

Comment: Did you add the Events unit to the uses clause in the interface section?

Comment: Sounds stupid, but sometimes these kind of errors disappear when you close the entire project and then reopen it.

Comment: What @KenWhite said - I have had this issue now that I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had already tried all the *common sense* suggestions like making sure the file was in the project and in the uses clause of the other units.

Since no one has posted a solution I tried [Ken White's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) and [Wouter van Nifterick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38813/wouter-van-nifterick) suggestions.

- closed the project and restarted the IDE - no change
- Searched every drive on my system for Events.pas or Events.dcu - the one in my project was the only one.

The **only** thing that worked, and I have no idea why, was to rename the Events.pas to something else. I renamed it using the Project Manager and recompiled. All the `Undeclared Identifier`errors simply disappeared. I renamed it back to `Events` and the errors came back. Who knew?

Just out of curiosity I did a text search over every pas and inc file on my system to see if `Events` was used as an identifier somewhere (I know it shouldn't make a difference but... ya never know). Nothing. No variables, types or functions called `Events`.

As a sanity check I created a simple project with a handful of units, one of which was called `Events` with a few type declarations. All the other units included it in their uses clause. The compiler had no trouble resolving the type identifiers. I have absolutely no clue why it choked on the `Events` unit in my other project.

**Update**

I finally figured out why I was getting this error. The package I was writing used the open tools api(OTA) so it required the `DesignIDE` package. `DesignIDE` is provided only as a precompiled dcp and bpl so the source is missing for everything except the handful of interface units exposed as extension points for the IDE. It turns out that one of the *hidden* units compiled into `DesignIDE` is called `Events`. I did not discover this until I migrated my package to a later version of Delphi and started getting `E2200 Package 'designide' already contains unit 'Events'`. This error message did not appear in Delphi 2007.

My attempt to isolate the problem in a simpler package could not reproduce it because I had excluded  the `DesignIDE` package from it's dependencies, not realizing that it was the source of the error.